# How can I retrieve data from firebase without refresh in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have Boolean value in Firebase Realtime database i want a updated value without a screen Refresh in flutter.
i want it to be updated streamline on flutter

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to handle your issue is to use "cloud_firestore" package.
i'll make u a sample code below..

Note : Before using Firestore, you must first have ensured you have initialized FlutterFire! follow this link: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initializing-flutterfire

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestWidgetState createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
      Firebas`eFirestore.instance.collection('your collection name in database here').snapshots();`

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const LinearProgressIndicator();
    }


//this way you can extract your data from DB

//Of course it totally depend on if your data in Db is nested or not. just adjust it with your needs
    return ListView(
      children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data =
            document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
        return Column(children: [
          PassDataToAnotherWidget(data),
        ]);
      }).toList(),
    );
  },
);
  }
}
```

Comment: OP mentioned "Firebase Realtime database" in their question, which is a different database. The approach with a `StreamBuilder` applies to the Realtime Database too, but its API will be different.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in the Firebase Realtime Database, you can listen to update to that data through its [`onValue` stream](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#read_value_events). You can use this stream in your widget tree by using a `StreamBuilder`:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('path_to_value');
  return Scaffold(
    StreamBuilder(
      stream: ref.onValue,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) return Text(snapshot.data!.snapshot.value);
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text(snapshot.error);
      }
    )
  )
```

I recommend watching this great code-along video: [The Firebase Realtime Database and Flutter - Firecasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXBJZD0fBa4)